# Change Icon activeIndex via React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, tabs, native-base

How to Change Icon activeIndex via React Native?
I'm using `native-base` module, but not work and just `activeIndex == 0` is active and my function not work.

**Code:**

```
import {Icon, Button} from 'native-base';
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.segmentClicked = this.segmentClicked.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      activeIndex: 0
    }
  }

  segmentClicked = (index) => {
    this.setState = ({
      activeIndex: index
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', borderTopWidth: 1, borderTopColor: '#eae5e5'}}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.segmentClicked(0)}
            active={this.state.activeIndex == 0}
          >
            <Icon name='ios-apps-outline'
              style={[this.state.activeIndex == 0 ? {} : {color: 'gray'}]}
            />
          </Button>
          <Button
            onPress={this.segmentClicked(1)}
            active={this.state.activeIndex == 1}
          >
            <Icon name='ios-list-outline'
              style={[this.state.activeIndex == 1 ? {} : {color: 'gray'}]}
            />
          </Button>
          <Button
            onPress={this.segmentClicked(2)}
            active={this.state.activeIndex == 2}
          >
            <Icon name='ios-people-outline'
              style={[this.state.activeIndex == 2 ? {} : {color: 'gray'}]}
            />
          </Button>
          <Button
            onPress={this.segmentClicked(3)}
            active={this.state.activeIndex == 3}
          >
            <Icon name='ios-bookmark-outline'
              style={[this.state.activeIndex == 3 ? {} : {color: 'gray'}]}
            />
          </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function when you write `this.segmentClicked(1)`. Instead you want to give a function that *will* be called when the `Button` is pressed.

You can e.g. create a new inlined arrow function.

```
<Button
  onPress={() => this.segmentClicked(1)}
  active={this.state.activeIndex == 1}
>
  <Icon name='ios-list-outline'
    style={[this.state.activeIndex == 1 ? {} : {color: 'gray'}]}
  />
</Button>
```

You also have to call the `setState` function, not assign a new value to it.

```
segmentClicked = (index) => {
  this.setState({
    activeIndex: index
  });
}
```

Comment: I Changed and nothing happened and same as past, 0 is active.

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei I found a second error. I updated the answer.

Comment: That is strange, because my segmentClicked not work, your segmentClicked  work. this was my segment Clicked:  ``` // segmentClicked = (index) => {
  //   this.setState = ({
  //     activeIndex: index
  //   })
  // }```

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei Yes, if you look closely you will see that you are writing `setState =`. You are not supposed to overwrite `setState`, but instead call it as a function `setState()`.

Comment: ah yes, Thank you. appreciate it